# Why is the Flutter empty Container behave differently with alignment in debug paint?

Tags: flutter, dart

At first ,I will make a Container with alignment (But no child) in its constructor , And you can see that the red color is like be hided with something transparent.
[image]

And If I remove the alignment , The red color seems normal
[image]

What's the meaning of this color difference?

Comment: Do your active `Widget Inspector`?  And use `Slecte Widget` or `Show Debug Paint`? The color show is the same but the darkness show different layout

Comment: YES, I have open Show Debug Paint . I don't know the darkness means for what?

Comment: It just like when you use stack, some layout on bottom, some on top. The darkness show the deepness I think. OR show not selected widget

Comment: @SamChan Thanks! I got it ! maybe the dark means  a Align widget which will be new when the alignment is set for Container

Comment: That's new for me, I usually use it to check padding :)